# rsyslog not filtering messages into separate log file

Tags: systemd, syslog, rsyslog

Somehow I can't get this working and I need some help.

I try to filter logs from syslog, written by a systemd service, into a separate log file. Currently I'm using `Debian`. Here is my rsyslog config located into `/etc/rsyslog.d/19-test.conf` with content

```
:msg,contains,"[frontend]"  -/var/log/frontend_app.log
```

Content of the systemd unit file:

```
[Service]
    ExecStart=/opt/test/current/venv/bin/python -m api.tasks.frontend_app
    StandardOutput=syslog
    WorkingDirectory=/opt/test/frontend/current
    StandardError=syslog
    User=coco
    ProtectSystem=full
    SyslogIdentifier=[frontend]
```

Now, when I run the service logs are inserted into `syslog` but not into `/var/log/frontend_app.log` but when I try this:

```
logger -p local1.info "[frontend] test message"
```

message is inserted OK into `/var/log/frontend_app.log`.

`/etc/rsyslog.conf` content:

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see
#           /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#module(load="imudp")
#input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
#module(load="imtcp")
#input(type="imtcp" port="514")


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


###############
#### RULES ####
###############

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*             /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*               -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
user.*              -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info           -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn           -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg             :omusrmsg:*
```

I can't seems to find why it behaves like this and what is the solution for this.

Thx!

Comment: If you remove your custom rsyslog configuration, do you see the logs appear in `/var/log/syslog`? That question will help determine whether the  problem is getting the logs from systemd->rsyslog or with the rsyslog filtering.

Comment: The logs appear in syslog. In fact I manage to fix it by using `:rawmsg` instead of `:msg`. Seems that `:msg` includes only the message without the   `SyslogIdentifier` while `:rawmsg` does include it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I managed to fix it by using `:rawmsg` instead of `:msg` so,

```
:rawmsg,contains,"[frontend]"  -/var/log/frontend_app.log
```

It seems that `:msg` msg does not contain `SyslogIdentifier` and only the log message while `:rawmsg` does include full message with timestamp(if enabled) and `SyslogIdentifier`.

More info here http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/properties.html#message-properties.